# Proving that simple transcendental extensions have infinite degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, extension-field

We are only considering subfields of $ℂ$.

Let $K$ be a field and $x$ be transcendental over $K$. The author proves that $[K(x):K]= \infty$ by simply stating "notice that the elements $1, x, x^2, ...$ are linearly independent over $K$."

I understand why such elements are linearly independent over $K$, however I don't see why that implies that $[K(x):K]=\infty$.

---

I would appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: Degree $N$ would mean that $1,x,\cdots, x^N$ were of necessity dependent.

Comment: @lulu. Sorry, I fail to see why. Could you elaborate?

Comment: How do you define "degree $N$"?  More generally, how do you define the degree of a field extension?

Comment: @lulu. Well, given the field extension $L:K$ one can see $L$ as a vector space over $K$. Let $B$ be any basis for such vector space, $[L:K] = |B|.$

Comment: Ok...and if a vector space has a basis of size $N$ then any $N+1$ elements of the vector space must be dependent.  This is a key result from linear algebra...the size of a basis is determined by the vector field.  Too few elements, and your set can not span.  Too many (as here) and they must be linearly dependent.